# I need help on this: Oracle keeps on giving me ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: oracle

I keep on getting ORA-00911: invalid character but where is my invalid character?

```
SELECT order_num
FROM orders
WHERE customer_num = '126'
  AND order_date = #10/15/2015#;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Answer (score 4):

It shows the exact position of the invalid character, notice the asterisk:

```
SQL> select order_num from orders where customer_num = '126' and order_date = #10/15/2015#;
select order_num from orders where customer_num = '126' and order_date = #10/15/2015#
                                                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

That is not a valid syntax for dates. Use one of the the below:

```
order_date = date'2015-10-15'
order_date = to_date('10/15/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```